# Fourier transform of a windowed cosine function

Tags: fourier-transform

I was doing some problems for practice and I came across this:

> $$f(t) = \cos(\omega_0t) \left[H\left(t+\frac{T}{2}\right) - H\left(t- \frac{T}{2}\right)\right]$$
>   where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside/ unit step function

I have not seen anything like this before and not even sure how I would even start on this?

I attempted to find the Fourier transform using the equation as normal but it's not going anywhere.

Where would you even start on this?

Comment: $FT(f.g)=FT(g)*FT(g)$ where "*" is convolution. But instead of writing you window as the difference of two Heavisides, I advise you to keep with $\Pi_{(-T,T)}$, because the FT of $\Pi_{(-T,T)}$ is sinc$(k\nu/T)$ (cardinal sine) (constant $k$ depends on the definition taken for the FT : with or without $\pi$ or $2\pi$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's define the Fourier transform of $f$ as 
$$\mathcal F\{f(t)\}=F(\omega )=\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }f(t)e^{-i\omega t}\mathrm dt$$

and observe that the Fourier transform of a product of functions is the convolution of the Fourier transform of the functions $\mathcal F\{f(t)\cdot g(t)\}=F(\omega)*G(\omega)$.

Observing that using the [rect function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function#Relation_to_the_boxcar_function), we have 
$$
\mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{t}{T}\right)=H\left(t+\frac{T}{2}\right) - H\left(t- \frac{T}{2}\right)
$$ 
and $$
f(t)=\cos(\omega_0 t)\cdot \mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{t}{T}\right)
$$
So we have
$$
\mathcal F\left\{ f(t)\right\}=\mathcal F\left\{ \cos(\omega_0 t)\cdot \mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{t}{T}\right)\right\}=\mathcal F\left\{ \cos(\omega_0 t)\right\}*\mathcal F\left\{ \mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{t}{T}\right)\right\}
$$
Observing that 
$$\mathcal F\left\{ \cos(\omega_0 t)\right\}= \pi\left[\delta(\omega-\omega_0)+\delta(\omega+\omega_0)\right]$$
and
$$
\mathcal F\left\{ \mathrm{rect}\left(\frac{t}{T}\right)\right\}=T\cdot\mathrm{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega}{2\pi/T}\right)
$$
we have
$$
F(\omega)=\pi T\left[\mathrm{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega-\omega_0}{2\pi/T}\right)+\mathrm{sinc}\left(\frac{\omega+\omega_0}{2\pi/T}\right)\right]
$$